# SpringCloudStream TestChannelBinderConfiguration Junits tests not working with Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, autowired, spring-cloud-stream, springmockito

1. pom.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.11</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>sample-project</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>sample-project</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       <!-- Spring Cloud Stream versions -->
       <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
       <spring-cloud-stream.version>3.2.7</spring-cloud-stream.version>
       <spring-cloud-stream-kinesis.version>2.2.0</spring-cloud-stream-kinesis.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
           <!-- Spring Cloud Stream dependencies -->
       <!-- start -->
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
         <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
         <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis</artifactId>
         <version>${spring-cloud-stream-kinesis.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
         <type>test-jar</type>
         <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
       </dependency>
   <!--     <dependency> -->
   <!--       <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId> -->
   <!--       <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId> -->
   <!--       <scope>test</scope> -->
   <!--     </dependency> -->
       <dependency>
         <groupId>software.amazon.msk</groupId>
         <artifactId>aws-msk-iam-auth</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.6</version>
       </dependency>
   <!--  end -->


       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
   <!-- Spring Cloud Stream dependency management -->
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
       <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   </project>
   ```
2. consumers.java

   ```
   //@Component
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   @ComponentScan("com.example.sampleproject.services")
   public class SampleConsumer {

   @Autowired
   private SampleService sampleService;

   @Bean
   public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
           return v -> sampleService.convertToUpperCase(v);
   }

   }
   ```
3. SampleService.java

   ```
    public interface SampleService {

   public String convertToUpperCase(String str);

    }
   ```
4. SampleServiceImpl.java

   ```
   @Service
   public class SampleServiceImpl  implements SampleService {

   @Autowired
   private SampleService2 sampleService2;

   public String convertToUpperCase(String str) {
       str = sampleService2.convertStringToLowerCase(str);
       return str.toUpperCase();
   }

   }
   ```
5. SampleService2.java

   ```
    public interface SampleService2 {

   public String convertStringToLowerCase(String str);
    }
   ```
6. SampleService2Impl.java

   ```
   @Service
   public class SampleService2Impl implements SampleService2 {

   public String convertStringToLowerCase(String str) {
       return str.toLowerCase();
   }

   }
   ```
7. SampleConsumerTests.java

   ```
   @SpringBootTest
   public class SampleConsumerTests {

   @MockBean
   private SampleService2 sampleService2;

   @Test
   public void sampleTest() {

       when(sampleService2.convertStringToLowerCase(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
        .thenReturn("mockedString");

       try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(
                   TestChannelBinderConfiguration.getCompleteConfiguration(
                           SampleConsumer.class))
                   .run("--spring.cloud.function.definition=uppercase")) {
           InputDestination source = context.getBean(InputDestination.class);
           OutputDestination target = context.getBean(OutputDestination.class);
           source.send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>("hello".getBytes()));
           assertThat(target.receive().getPayload()).isEqualTo("HELLO".getBytes());
       }
   }
   }
   ```

This is my sample springBootApplication where I written tests using testBinder, below are the issues i'm facing.

In sampleConsumers.java

1. When @Component is enabled getting below error
   @Component (Enabled)
   //@EnableAutoConfiguration    (Disabled)
   //@ComponentScan("com.example.sampleproject.services") (Disabled)

Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredTokenException; Request ID: *****************; Proxy: null)

2. When @Component is disabled and @EnableAutoConfiguration is enabled getting below error
   //@Component (Disabled)
   @EnableAutoConfiguration (Enabled)

Field sampleService in com.example.sampleproject.consumers.SampleConsumer required a bean of type 'com.example.sampleproject.services.SampleService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.sampleproject.services.SampleService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

3. When @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan it works fine
   //@Component (Disabled)
   @EnableAutoConfiguration    (Enabled)
   @ComponentScan("com.example.sampleproject.services") (Enabled)

a) why this implementation not working with @component?
b) why always we need to use @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan annotations ?
c) why mockito not working with this ? how to fix mockito issue ?

1. As per mock this assert should fail where "hello" is replaced with "mockedString", but mock not working.
   i.e:
   when(sampleService2.convertStringToLowerCase(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
   .thenReturn("mockedString");

   assertThat(target.receive().getPayload()).isEqualTo("HELLO".getBytes());
2. why this Implementation won't work with @Component  but it works with @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan annotations ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to work with Mockito.
TestChannelBinder was designed for basic unit/integration testing.